# How to find which python package(s) require(s) certain dependency?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, conda

Ideally using a one-liner, without the need for a dedicated script (e.g. looping and grepping over `pipdeptree -p` output with many packages). Ideally using standard tools (unless the extra package required is actively maintained).

Importantly, the package (said dependency) is not installed, so its reverse dependencies cannot be established using `pipdeptree -r -p`.

---

This was motivated (but is off-topic here) by `"UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'No module named service_identity'."`

Comment: What's wrong with `pipdeptree`?

Comment: If the library in question is not installed then [_`johnnydep`_](https://pypi.org/project/johnnydep/) is the only somewhat helpful tool I can think of. But it will not give you reverse dependencies as far as I know. It is an impossible task, because it requires checking everything on _PyPI_. So your best bet is probably some database like [_`libraries.io`_](https://libraries.io/pypi)

Comment: For example: https://libraries.io/pypi/service-identity/dependents for PyPI and https://libraries.io/conda/service_identity/dependents for conda

Comment: Also this: https://deps.dev/pypi/service-identity/21.1.0/dependents -- I guess it has a JSON REST API as well, that you could maybe use for one-liners.